# Solving this differential equation example

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve this differential equation analytically

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=ry(\frac{y}{\theta}-1)(1-\frac{y}{K})$$

and I have started by separating the variables to each side

$$\frac{dy}{\left(\frac{y}{\theta }-1\right)\left(1-\frac{y}{K}\right)y}=rdt$$

now however I am uncertain about how to continue, is it correct to simply split up the left side into three separate fractions?

$\frac{dy}{\left(\frac{y}{\theta }-1\right)}$ , $\frac{dy}{\left(1-\frac{y}{K}\right)}$ and $\frac{dy}{y}$

If so I know the rightmost fraction is ln y but how about the other fractions? I know a trick that is available is

$\frac{u'}{u}=ln\:u\:$ but not how/if I can apply it here.

Comment: Perform a partial fraction decomposition and integrate.

Comment: I guess you mean $(\ln u)'=\frac{u'}{u}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$\frac{dy}{\left(\frac{y}{\theta }-1\right)\left(1-\frac{y}{K}\right)y}=rdt$$
Use [fraction decomposition method](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/partial-fractions.)  and write it as:
$$\dfrac  1 {\left(\frac{y}{\theta }-1\right)\left(1-\frac{y}{K}\right)y}=\frac{A}{\frac y{\theta} -1}+\dfrac B{(1-\frac{y}{K})}+\dfrac Cy$$
Find the constants $A,B,C$ then integrate.

---

$$1=y^2\left(-\frac{A}{K}+\frac{B}{\theta }-\frac{C}{\theta K}\right)+y\left(A-B+\frac{C}{\theta }+\frac{C}{K}\right)+\left(-C\right)$$
$$ \implies  \left(-\frac{A}{K}+\frac{B}{\theta }+\frac{1}{\theta K}\right)=0$$
and also:
$$\left(A-B-\frac{1}{\theta }-\frac{1}{K}\right)=0$$
It's a system of two equations. From the second equation you have ;
$$A=-\left(-B-\frac{1}{\theta }-\frac{1}{K}\right)$$
Put $A$ iin the first equation and deduce $B$

Comment: Ok I'll try, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome @P.ython then integrate with $ln$ function.

Comment: That gave me 
$1\:=\:Ay\left(1-\frac{y}{K}\right)+By\left(\frac{y}{\theta }-1\right)+C\left(\frac{y}{\theta }-1\right)\left(1-\frac{y}{K}\right)$

Not sure how I find the constants now

Comment: collect the terms with $y^2$ since you have no y on the left side of the equation the coefficients should be equal to zero. Do the same for the coefficents of y . and collect the others terms and set them equal to 1 since you have 1 on the left side @P.ython

Comment: Then I only get C= -1 correct?

Comment: Yes thats correct $C=-1$ Find A and B @P.ython

Comment: Are A and B not zero? Since the left side is only a constant 1?

Comment: No it cant be zero @P.ython it's the sum of  coefficents of $y^2$ and of $y$ that is zero

Comment: Hmm, I have 
$1=y^2\left(-\frac{A}{K}+\frac{B}{\theta }-\frac{C}{\theta K}\right)+y\left(A-B+\frac{C}{\theta }+\frac{C}{K}\right)+\left(-C\right)$
Do you mean set the first and second parenthesis equal to zero, I cant see how to solve A and B then

Comment: @P.ython you already know that $c=-1$ so put $-1$ instead of c in your equation thats first then the coefficents of $y^2$ is equal zero and that of $y$ too you have a system of two equations for A and B

Comment: Yes I mean the first parenthesis is equal zero and the second two you have a system of two equations in A and B thats easy to solve @P.ython

Comment: Sorry @Aryadeva I am really trying to see what you describe but can't so far. If you have the energy can you show me how you mean in steps?

Comment: If I only had A, B and C in the parentheses it would be straightforward but now I have /K and /theta

Comment: I added some lines I hope it's mire clear @P.ython

Comment: Then that gives me $A=B+\frac{1}{\theta }+\frac{1}{K}$ and $B=\frac{\left(\frac{1}{K^2}\right)}{\left(\frac{1}{\theta }-\frac{1}{K}\right)}$  ?

Comment: This is still pretty difficult to integrate and does this show we are not likely to find a real answer? @Aryadeva

Comment: Good job Yes it's maybe silly but you know you need to lear to perform partial fraction decomposition since it's used a lot for integrals and differential equations @P.ython

Comment: Thank you for your help I'll upvote after :) The question mentioned you are not likely to find a real solution so I guess they mean it is still complex. I'll work on my fractional decomposition!

Comment: The most important is to learn so next time you gace this you will know that you have to use fraction decomposition @P.ython Have a nice night or day.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112873/discussion-between-p-ython-and-aryadeva).